# Role slash command with subcommands add/remove not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a slash command with subcommands to add or remove roles from a member, for now my code gives the error "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined" at line 46:40. (Target.roles.add)

I don't have any idea how to fix it because I'm not a professional at discord.js.‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

The code:

```
const { Message, guild, message, CommandInteraction } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "role",
    description: "Command for the owner to block people from using the bot",
    Perms: "MANAGE_ROLES", // Maybe different for you but idk
    options: [
        {
            name: "type",
            description: "Choose what do you want to do with the role.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "add",
                    value: "add"
                },
                {
                    name: "remove",
                    value: "remove"
                }
              
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "role",
            description: "Enter the role name",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "member",
            description: "Mention the member to add/remove role",
            type: "USER",
            required: true,
        }
    ],
    /**
     * @param {Message} message
     */
     execute(interaction, message, guild, member, client) {
        const { options, reply } = interaction;
        const type = interaction.options.getString('type');
        const role = interaction.options.getString('role');
        const Target = interaction.options.getUser('member');
        const findrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "${role}");
       
                 switch(type) {
                case "add" : {
                    if (!findrole) {
                        return interaction.reply({ content: `You entered invalid role name!`, ephemeral: false });
                  
                    }
                    if (findrole) {
                        Target.roles.add(role);
                        interaction.reply({ content: `Added ${role} to ${usr}`, allowedMentions: { users: []}})
                    }
                }
                break;
                case "remove" : {
                    if (!findrole) {
                        
                      return interaction.reply({ content: `Role does not exist.`, ephemeral: false });
                    } else {
Target.roles.remove(findrole); 
interaction.reply({ content: `Removed ${role} from ${usr}`, allowedMentions: { users: []}})              
                    }
if (!Target.has.findrole) {
interaction.reply({ content: `${usr} does not have this role.`, allowedMentions: { users: []}});
                          }
                      break
                    }
                }
              }
           }
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Is `Target` of type `guildMember`? If not it is not going to work. `Target`needs to be a `guildMember` if you want to assign server-roles

Comment: yes it is a mentioned user in a guild

Comment: Have you checked, if `Target` is null or undefined?

Comment: If so, check if you have enabled the required `intents` when creating your client

Comment: I have every intent enabled

Comment: If you do `console.log(Target)`, what does it show?

Comment: No problem haha :) I'd be happy if you mark the answer as accepted then ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using only

```js
const target = interaction.member
```

... for getting the member that used the command.

---

Also make sure to `await` the `roles.add()`function, because it returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
[...]

async execute(interaction, message, guild, member, client) {
   const target = interaction.member

   // Find your role

   await target.roles.add(<role>)
}
```

If you don't specify your `execute` function to be `async` you won't be able to use `await`

Comment: Bro it gives a role for mentioned user so i don't think i need interaction.member for this

Comment: @Rice Okay, but how am I supposed to know this if you don't specify it in your question? ^^